# Visual Studio 2013 extra folders

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Every time I open a solution visual studio creates an extra folder "Visual Studio 2013" in the root directory of the solution.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this happen too a couple times (for me, it was because the VS settings etc. were all stored on a network drive that went down while VS was running, which messed up the config).

You'll need to:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Open Visual Studio. In the options pages, go to `Environment->Import and Export Settings` and make sure the path there is correct. It should look something like `c:\users\[user]\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`. Do the same for the three paths in `Projects and Solutions->General`. Save the options.
3. Close VS, and repeat step 2 if necessary (now that the settings are being saved in the appropriate location).
4. With VS closed, look in the registry at the immediate values under the key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0` for any other file paths that still aren't correct (they should all be full paths), and fix them. Be careful not to remove trailing slashes where present, they matter.

Some of these steps may not be completely necessary, or may need to be repeated (I'm not entirely sure which since I didn't have the time to debug this thoroughly the last time it happened -- I just brute-force fixed all the broken paths I found until it worked). This should be enough to get you on the right track, however.

You can safely delete the spurious Visual Studio 2013 folders that got created.